# constant value for case label for switch statement in c and c++ but show different behaviour

Tags: c++, c, switch-statement, constants

For same program in c and c++ when we use constant integer variable as case label it is valid only in c++ and not in c also when we use constant integer array member as case label then it is not valid for both c and c++. What is  the main reason for this behaviour ?

```
//for c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    const int a=90;
    switch(90)
    {
    case a://error : case label does not reduce to an integer constant
        printf("error");
        break;
    }

    const int arr[3]={88,89,90};
    switch(90)
    {
    case arr[2]://error : case label does not reduce to an integer constant
        printf("Error");
        break;
    }
}
```

```
//for c++
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    const int a=90;
    switch(90)
    {
    case a:
        printf("No error");
        break;
    }

    const int arr[3]={88,89,90};
    switch(90)
    {
    case arr[2]://error 'arr' cannot appear in a constant-expression
        printf("Error");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason for the behaviour is what C and C++ each consider to be constant expressions.

Comment: Despite some very similar syntax, C and C++ are two *very* different languages, with different semantics and behavior, often for things that might seem very similar. This is one such case where C and C++ differ.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the main reason for this behaviour ?

The main reason for this is the 2018 C standard says of `case` labels in 6.8.4.2 3 “The expression of each `case` label shall be an integer constant expression…” and defines an *integer constant expression* in 6.6 6:

> An *integer constant expression* shall have integer type and shall only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants, character constants, `sizeof` expressions whose results are integer constants, `_Alignof` expressions, and floating constants that are the immediate operands of casts. Cast operators in an integer constant expression shall only convert arithmetic types to integer types, except as part of an operand to the `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operator.

whereas the 2017 C++ standard says of `case` labels in 9.4.2 “the *constant-expression* shall be a converted constant expression…” and defines a *converted constant expression* in 8.20 with four pages of text involving *core constant expression*, *integer constant expression*, and more.

In summary, the C++ standard is broader about what it requires a language implementation to evaluate at translation time.

The term “constant expression” is a misnomer. A more apt description is that these are expressions that the language implementation is required to be able to resolve to a specific value when translating a program. The C++ standard requires more of the implementation than the C standard does.